# Navigating backward produces "Pending Navigations still processing" exception

Tags: c#, maui

There is no problem when  I navigate from master page to detail page. But the reverse produces the following exception.

[image]

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Pending Navigations still processing
> Source=Microsoft.Maui.Controls   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.Microsoft.Maui.IStackNavigation.RequestNavigation(NavigationRequest
> eventArgs)    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.SyncNavigationStack(Boolean
> animated, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.ShellSectionHandler.OnNavigationRequested(Object
> sender, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.InvokeNavigationRequest(NavigationRequestedEventArgs
> args)    at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.d__86.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellSection.d__70.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.Maui.Dispatching.DispatcherExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.Maui.Dispatching.DispatcherExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> at
> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ShellNavigationManager.d__14.MoveNext()
> at MauiClient.Pages.DetailPage.<Back_Clicked>d__1.MoveNext() in
> C:\Projects\MauiClient\MauiClient\Pages\DetailPage.xaml.cs:line 16

Complete repo can be found [here](https://github.com/pstricks-fans/MauiClient). Below are the snippets.

**Configuration:**

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services
            .AddHttpClient<MonkeyService>();

        builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<MasterViewModel>()
            .AddSingleton<MasterPage>();

        builder.Services
            .AddTransient<DetailViewModel>()
            .AddTransient<DetailPage>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

**AppShell:**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(DetailPage), typeof(DetailPage));
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Monkey
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Location { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Details { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Image { get; set; } = default!;
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class MonkeyService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    public MonkeyService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }


    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<Monkey>?> GetMonkeys()
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.montemagno.com/monkeys.json");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<Monkey>>();
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<Monkey>();
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public partial class MasterViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly MonkeyService service;

    public MasterViewModel(MonkeyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }


    public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; } = new();


    public async Task ReloadAsync()
    {
        Monkeys.Clear();

        var monkeys = await service.GetMonkeys();

        foreach (var monkey in monkeys ?? Enumerable.Empty<Monkey>())
            Monkeys.Add(monkey);
    }
}


[QueryProperty(nameof(Monkey), nameof(Monkey))]
public partial class DetailViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly MonkeyService service;
    public DetailViewModel(MonkeyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }


    [ObservableProperty]
    Monkey monkey = default!;
}
```

**Pages:**

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiClient.Models"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiClient.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiClient.Pages.MasterPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:MasterViewModel"
             Title="Master Page"
             >
    <CollectionView 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
                    >

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Monkey" >
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
{
    public MasterPage(MasterViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = model;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (BindingContext is MasterViewModel model)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(nameof(OnAppearing));
            await model.ReloadAsync();
        }
    }

    private async void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(nameof(OnSelectionChanged));

        var navparam = new Dictionary<string, object?>
        {
            [nameof(Monkey)] = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Monkey
        };

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailPage), navparam);
    }
}
```

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiClient.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiClient.Pages.DetailPage"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:DetailViewModel"
             Title="Detail Page"
             >   
    
    <VerticalStackLayout  >
        <Label Text="{Binding Monkey.Name}" />
        <Button Text="Back" Clicked="Back_Clicked"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>    
    
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public DetailPage(DetailViewModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = model;
    }

    private async void Back_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested on Android but works as normal but not on Windows.

Comment: Seems MS has forgotten to test the Windows platform ... DragDrop does not work either on Windows

Comment: `SwipeView` also does not work in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing with gesture as follows works.

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
        Command="{Binding GoToDetailCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:MasterViewModel}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

Here are the updated parts:

```cs
public partial class MasterViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // Other parts are the same and left for the sake of simplicity!



    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GoToDetailAsync(Monkey monkey)
    {
        if (monkey is not null)
        {
            var navparam = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                [nameof(DetailViewModel.Monkey)] = monkey
            };

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DetailPage), navparam);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage ...>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" SelectionMode="None">

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Monkey" >
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Command="{Binding GoToDetailCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:MasterViewModel}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>
```